# Eureka Client Re-registration is taking time

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I have a service (let's call A) that registers itself to Eureka and I can see that status as online within few mins(< ~2mins) in Spring Boot Admin GUI. After some time, Service A shutdown abruptly and this also reflects in Spring Boot Admin GUI after few mins(< ~2mins. This is due to eureka.server.expected-client-renewal-interval-seconds and few other properties). Now Service A started again and I can see from the logs it is successfully registered with Eureka Service but Spring Boot Admin GUI shows that the instance is offline and approx after 10mins only the instance is showing online.

Could you please let me know why Eureka is taking ~10mins to mark the instance as Online? Are there any properties I can use to bring down the 10mins delay further down?

Thanks in advance